# How do you write a simple screen sharing program using C#?

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I am interested in trying to create a screen sharing program in C#. I have found a blog post on the Windows Desktop Sharing API  (http://blogs.msdn.com/ts/archive/2007/03/08/windows-desktop-sharing-api.aspx) but I'm uncertain how to even get started with it. Does anyone have a simple example they could share (preferably in C# or VB.net) of how to use this API or using a different method? ...or is it not practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://www.teknoportal.gen.tr/english/technology_news.asp?haber=385) might get you started in the right direction. It has some sample code written in vb.net, check it out.